# unrecognized selector sent to instance (DTCoreText+UILabel)

Tags: ios, objective-c, dtcoretext

I get the error:

```
-[__NSCFType lineBreakMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

When the following code finishes to execute:

```
 NSDictionary* options = @{ NSTextSizeMultiplierDocumentOption: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 1.0],
                                                            DTDefaultFontFamily: @"Helvetica Neue",
                                                            };
 NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTMLData:[@"HTML TEXT HERE" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:options documentAttributes:NULL];
 attrStr = [attrStr copy];

 UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
 lbl.attributedText = attrStr;

 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MOTD"
                                                 message:@""
                                                delegate:nil
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [alert setValue:lbl forKey:@"accessoryView"];
 [self Load_list_Data];
 [alert show];
```

My project is targeted for iOS 8+.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are targeting iOS 8, why are you using DTCoreText instead of the system provided `- [NSAttributedString initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:]` to parse HTML?

Comment: Speed, the DTCoreText lib is orders of magnitude faster. Using it to render some HTML in a table that can be 1000s of records.(I only render what is visible and its still to slow with the system provided function)

Answer (score 5):

For some reason even though I'm using iOS 8 forcing iOS 6 attributes fixed the issue:

```
     NSDictionary* options = @{ NSTextSizeMultiplierDocumentOption: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 1.0],
                                DTDefaultFontFamily: @"Helvetica Neue",DTUseiOS6Attributes: [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                                };
```